# Android adb install returns error:device not found - Windows 7

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [adb cannot find my device for Android debugging. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271008/adb-cannot-find-my-device-for-android-debugging-why)

I'm trying to download my hello world Android app. to my Motorola backflip, it's connected to a USB port on the PC and I've previously downloaded the USB drivers for the phone.  adb devices does not seem to list the phone either.  What can I do to get this working?  I am running Windows 7.

TY,
Fred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the phone itself you need to allow development in one of the menus. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because your phone isn't recognized by your windows pc. I suggest to see if it's on the device management menu.

Answer (score 2):

Afew things to try:

1. Use a different USB port
2. Enable debug mode on the phone
3. Do NOT mount the media to the computer if you want to use adb