# adb error:device not found

Tags: device, adb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [adb cannot find my device for Android debugging. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271008/adb-cannot-find-my-device-for-android-debugging-why)

i am new to android development. i am getting "adb error: device not found" in my command prompt when i am using this command "adb shell" .. i am using eclipse with android sdk in windows xp..

What i did is i was updated my android sdk version 2.2 to 3 .
before this updation it was working perfectly but after updation it is showing "adb error: device not found"

Can any one please help me

Answer (score 3):

At least in the version of androidSDK I downloaded it says that the adb has moved folders, now you can find it in android-sdk/platform-tools instead of android-sdk/tools

You need to reconfigure you environment_variable path to this new path and it should fix it.

You can check if your adb is working by running

```
$adb devices
```

A list of your connected devices should appear (check that you DO have connected devices). If the message "adb is not recognized as an internal or external android" you didn't set up adb correctly. 
Try rebooting and take a look at [this post](http://theunlockr.com/2009/10/06/how-to-set-up-adb-usb-drivers-for-android-devices/) it could be helpful

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had the same issue on my linuxmint box and tried $adb devices after running an emulator. I was told in my terminal that $adb devices is not installed and told how to get it oinstalled. after running - apt-get install android-tools-adb it worked.

Answer (score 0):

check if your emulator is running and/or your device is plugged into the usb port, if it is a real device, also check wheter or not usb debugging is activated